# Convert Infinity to 0 with Ruby

Tags: ruby, floating-point, infinite

Is there a method to convert `Infinity` to `0`?

If a calculation returns `Infinity`, I want to represent it as `0`. I tried to use `to_i` as in `(+1.0/0.0).to_i`, but that threw a `FloatDomainError` error.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to represent Infinity as 0?

Comment: Catch exception `FloatDomainError` and return 0 if so.

Answer (score 3):

```
 > x = (+1.0/0.0)
 => Infinity
 > x = 0 if x.infinite?
 => 0
> x
 => 0
```

Comment: Or `x = Float::INFINITY #=> Infinity`, `x.is_a? Fixnum #=> true `

Answer (score 2):

There are two infinities: positive, and negative.  The method [Float#infinite?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html#method-i-infinite-3F) returns +1 for positive infinity, -1 for negative infinity, and nil if the number is neither.  So:

```
if f.infinite?
  f = 0
end
```

This works because +1 and -1 are both *truthy* values, and nil is a *falsy* value.

If it is only positive infinity you wish to replace with zero, then:

```
if f.infinite? == 1
  f = 0
end
```

and similarly for negative infinity.

If the number might be an integer or some other kind of Numeric that is not a float, then convert it to a float first:

```
if f.to_f.infinite?
  f = 0
end
```

Comment: Note: there is no `Fixnum#infinite?` so you may want `f.to_f.infinite?`

Answer (score 1):

You can use string interpolation for this:

```
"#{+1.0/0.0}".to_i  #=> 0
```

Comment: That actually worked pretty damn well! Any drawbacks?

Comment: i think it is basically casting a string to integer so if the result is not an integer its decimal ommited.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = 1.0/0 #=> Infinity
result.to_f.infinite? ? 0 : result
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try testing using infinite?. Something like the following:

```
def no_infinites num
  num.to_f.infinite? ? 0 : num
end
```

This returns 0 if `num` is `±Infinity`, and `num` otherwise. The return value will be whatever type `num` is if `num` is finite

Answer (score 0):

Use 0.0 || 1.0/0.0, this will not work